# shell script: send Command to serial console and get result

Tags: shell, serial-port, freebsd, bsd

On my Computer is a Cisco WS-C3550 connected to serial interface, I can connect with following Command to the Device:

```
cu -l /dev/cuau0 -s 9600
```

If I connected to the Device i send following command

```
show interface FastEthernet0/2
```

And the output of this command I want to use in a shell script to get some values, how can I do this? I use FreeBSD (pfsense 2.0.1) as operating system.

I try anything like

```
echo 'show interface FastEthernet0/2' > cu -l /dev/cuau0 -s 9600 > test.log
```

But this dosen't work. I get following error:

> Ambiguous output redirect.

Comment: could it be echo 'show interface FastEthernet0/2' | cu -l /dev/cuau0 -s 9600 > test.log

Comment: yes it works but now I can't exit from this console, when I insert this command there will be shown a command prompt. If I'am on cu terminal i cant exit with '~.' on a new line. Is it possible to give multiple commands to cu command?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo -e 'show interface FastEthernet0/2\n~.' | cu -l /dev/cuau0 -s 9600 > test.log
```

`~.` drops the connection see http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cu&sektion=1

Comment: Thx for your answer, but this dosen't work, I will get the prompt after run that command and the content of test.log is 'Connected'

Comment: See above comment. If I enter this command on prompt, there comes a command prompt in a new line and in the test.log file is following content: 'Connected' thats all